# Use filter on a state without using the setState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I know it is recommended by react to use the setCommand to update my state but I can't find a fastest way to update command without using filter directly on the state. Can someone show me how you would do it with the setCommand?

**Correction**
I just forgot the return in the filter:

```
function useCommand() {
   const [command, setCommand] = useState([]);

   const handleCommand = (barcode) => {
      let newCommand = command.filter(item => { return (item.code == barcode) ? item.quantity++ : item})
      setCommand(newCommand)
   }

   return [command, handleCommand];
}
```

Comment: Before wondering if you can do this with `setCommand`, you should first check if your current code works. Does it update the command state? Are related components updating?

Comment: it is working, the quantity is updating on my screen

Comment: What happens with the corrected code when you increase the quantity of an item for the 1st time? Is it included in the `command`?

Comment: @fgkolf it is, as you can see in https://jsfiddle.net/3sxbq7f2/ . but you have to update the state with setCommand, so you need a need a new variable. I m new on react so I can really explain why

Answer (score 1):

`filter` function returns a new array and does not modify the existing array. Hence, you can use `filter` directly on the state, as it will not modify the state. In your case, you are already creating a new array with `command.filter(article => {(article.code == barcode) ? article.quantity++ : article})`, but you are not storing that new array in a variable. Once you store that in a variable, you can simply use that variable to set the state using `setCommand`.

Here is the code:

```
function useCommand() {
   const [command, setCommand] = useState([]);

   const handleCommand = (barcode) => {
      var newCommand = command.filter(article => {(article.code == barcode) ? article.quantity++ : article});
      setCommand(newCommand);
   }

   return [command, handleCommand];
}
```

Comment: I already tried this but it returns an empty array in newCommand

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do here: `.filter(article => {(article.code == barcode) ? article.quantity++ : article})`? The filter function expects true or false as return value, but it seems that you are not returning any thing

Comment: Also, your initial state is an empty array, then you are using filter, which essentially will decrease the items in the array, but I don't see anyway or a function to put data into the array. you are returning `handleCommand` function which will filter the array, but since the array is already empty, there is nothing to filter, hence it always gives empty array. You need to return a function that could put data items into the `command` array.